# Refreshing vim file from within a function

Tags: buffers, functions

I am trying to do a shortcut to resave a file with cmd-S. And if the file is of type `vim`, it will also re-source `%`. Here is what I have:

```
function SaveFile()
    w
    if &filetype ==? 'vim'
        so %
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap  <leader>S         :silent call SaveFile()<CR>
```

However, I get the following error:

> E127: Cannot redefine function SaveFile: It is in use

Why is this so? What do I need to do to fix this issue? Is `:so %` not allowed in a function?

Comment: Check what error means with `:h E127`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that functions cannot be redefined without `!` (as in `function!`). This is only partially true:

```
                                *E127* *E122*
            When a function by this name already exists and [!] is
            not used an error message is given.  There is one
            exception: When sourcing a script again, a function
            that was previously defined in that script will be
            silently replaced.
            When [!] is used, an existing function is silently
            replaced.  Unless it is currently being executed, that
            is an error.
            NOTE: Use ! wisely.  If used without care it can cause
            an existing function to be replaced unexpectedly,
            which is hard to debug.
```

I actually do not use `!` anymore, but I believe in old versions of vim it was required to be able to re-source a script at runtime and have function/command definitions work. You might want to check on your version.

---

A more idiomatic way to accomplish your setup is to split the two (this is effectively what I do):

```
" ~/.vim/vimrc, or some other globally-sourced file
nnoremap <leader>fs :write<CR>
```

and

```
" ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vim.vim

" two options: a dedicated map
nnoremap <buffer> <localleader>ef :source %<CR>
" or an autocommand
augroup SourceVim
  autocmd! * <buffer>
  autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> source %
augroup END
```

(I do [something similar in clojure with fireplace's `:Require`](https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/1e334ed90a7f5f731c9b5526207e5a69eb9b47ca/links/vim/after/ftplugin/clojure.vim#L25))

Comment: Why not `:update` instead of `:write`?

Comment: OP used write @Matt , but also sometimes you want the effect of a write (such as something that watches your code and runs tests or some such)